# react native the view freezes after taking a picture of the camera. (Image-crop-picker) android

Tags: react-native, android-camera, freeze

as soon as I shoot a picture from my android Device (Samsung galaxy s9) over the camera with the react-native-image-crop-picker and then go back the view stops and freezes and the app closes automatically after 30 seconds. there are also no errors in android Logcat.

but if I have the Metro bundler on and debug JS Remotely then the image crop picker works fine. and I continue the system quite normally.

I have another app where I also use react-native-image-crop-picker and there it works flawlessly without any problems.

what could that be? I can not explain it.

- "react": "16.8.3",
- react-native version 0.59.1
- "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.24.1",

  - MacBook down and restarted.
  - android gradlew clean running.
  - node module uninstalled and reinstalled
  - react-native link executed
  - app deleted from the device
  - app reinstalled with react-native run-android

options = {
            mediaType: 'photo',
            width: 1280,
            height: 1024,
            cropping: true,
            compressImageQuality: 0.5,
        };

let dateiArray = await Functions.getImageFromKamera(options);